Snowflake regex pattern
I'm trying to write a regex in Snowflake to return TRUE when there is a match for the criteria of 3 or more characters repeated in a string.
For example:
"Hello" should return FALSE
"Helooo" should return TRUE
"aaa" should return TRUE
"Helo how dooo you do?" should return TRUE
SELECT 'aaa' as text,      REGEXP_COUNT(text, '([a-zA-Z])\1{2,}') > 0 AS pattern_match;
Here is my attempt, but it returns FALSE. In traditional (POSIX) regex, this works as expected, but in Snowflake, it does not. Can someone help me understand what's wrong?

the back reference on the matching side is not supported. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-regexp#using-backreferences

so you have to fully expand that match aaa|bbb|ccc|... yourself, at which point you have 52 patterns

Update Your regex pattern as: '([a-zA-Z])\\1{2,}'.
Snowflake SQL query is
SELECT  'aaa' as text,
    REGEXP_COUNT('aaa', '([a-zA-Z])\\1{2,}') > 0 AS pattern_match;

SELECT  'aaa hello wwworld' as text,
    REGEXP_COUNT('aaa hello wwworld', '([a-zA-Z])\\1{2,}') > 0 AS pattern_match;

This should work according to snowflake regex docs.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-regexp

I have tried this and it is not working. It is returning me an error: 100048 (2201B): Invalid regular expression: '([a-zA-Z])\1{2,}', invalid escape sequence: \1

can you check with this query ? SELECT 'aaa' as text, REGEXP_SUBSTR('aaa', '([a-zA-Z])\\1{2,}') AS pattern_match;
Are you getting valid response or not @DB_apprentice ?

No valid response. Error that i pasted in upper comment.

So, regex pattern is correct. '([a-zA-Z])\\1{2,}'. @DB_apprentice  Please check SELECT 'aaa' as text, REGEXP_COUNT('aaa', '([a-zA-Z])\\1{2,}', 1, 'i') AS pattern_match;

the \1 is a backreference and Snowflake does not support these in the match side (they can be used in the replace side though). https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-regexp#using-backreferences

According to previous comment of DB_apprentice REGEXP_SUBSTR('aaa', '([a-zA-Z])\\1{2,}') is working perfectly in Snowflake DB. So, if we use CASE statement here it will work perfectly. reference query: SELECT CASE WHEN(REGEXP_SUBSTR('aaa', '([a-zA-Z])\\1{2,}') IS NOT NULL) THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END AS pattern_match @SimeonPilgrim

From what you're doing, you seem not to need the \1 statement. Try your regular expression as
REGEXP_LIKE( text , '[a-zA-Z]{3,}')
So the whole instruction will look like this
Select 'aaa' as text, REGEXP_LIKE( text , '[a-zA-Z]{3,}');

With that approach, every string that has letters in it will be true. For example the word "Hey" has return value TRUE, which is not the desired outcome. I want to get TRUE if the string has 3 or more repeated characters.
